Public mint but merkle proof exists
I want to programmatically mint this Base Mainnet NFT: NFT Base Scan code
The mint is open to everyone, but when I decode my transaction: TX Link, I can see that there still exits merkle proof that is used to verify my mint
When I read the contract itself, I found the claim function, along with the verifyClaim one in Drop.sol:
function claim(
        address _receiver,
        uint256 _quantity,
        address _currency,
        uint256 _pricePerToken,
        AllowlistProof calldata _allowlistProof,
        bytes memory _data
    ) public payable virtual override {
        _beforeClaim(_receiver, _quantity, _currency, _pricePerToken, _allowlistProof, _data);

        uint256 activeConditionId = getActiveClaimConditionId();

        verifyClaim(activeConditionId, _dropMsgSender(), _quantity, _currency, _pricePerToken, _allowlistProof);

        // Update contract state.
        claimCondition.conditions[activeConditionId].supplyClaimed += _quantity;
        claimCondition.supplyClaimedByWallet[activeConditionId][_dropMsgSender()] += _quantity;

        // If there's a price, collect price.
        _collectPriceOnClaim(address(0), _quantity, _currency, _pricePerToken);

        // Mint the relevant tokens to claimer.
        uint256 startTokenId = _transferTokensOnClaim(_receiver, _quantity);

        emit TokensClaimed(activeConditionId, _dropMsgSender(), _receiver, startTokenId, _quantity);

        _afterClaim(_receiver, _quantity, _currency, _pricePerToken, _allowlistProof, _data);
    }

function verifyClaim(
        uint256 _conditionId,
        address _claimer,
        uint256 _quantity,
        address _currency,
        uint256 _pricePerToken,
        AllowlistProof calldata _allowlistProof
    ) public view virtual returns (bool isOverride) {
        ClaimCondition memory currentClaimPhase = claimCondition.conditions[_conditionId];
        uint256 claimLimit = currentClaimPhase.quantityLimitPerWallet;
        uint256 claimPrice = currentClaimPhase.pricePerToken;
        address claimCurrency = currentClaimPhase.currency;

        /*
         * Here `isOverride` implies that if the merkle proof verification fails,
         * the claimer would claim through open claim limit instead of allowlisted limit.
         */
        if (currentClaimPhase.merkleRoot != bytes32(0)) {
            (isOverride, ) = MerkleProof.verify(
                _allowlistProof.proof,
                currentClaimPhase.merkleRoot,
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        _claimer,
                        _allowlistProof.quantityLimitPerWallet,
                        _allowlistProof.pricePerToken,
                        _allowlistProof.currency
                    )
                )
            );
        }

        if (isOverride) {
            claimLimit = _allowlistProof.quantityLimitPerWallet != 0
                ? _allowlistProof.quantityLimitPerWallet
                : claimLimit;
            claimPrice = _allowlistProof.pricePerToken != type(uint256).max
                ? _allowlistProof.pricePerToken
                : claimPrice;
            claimCurrency = _allowlistProof.pricePerToken != type(uint256).max && _allowlistProof.currency != address(0)
                ? _allowlistProof.currency
                : claimCurrency;
        }

        uint256 supplyClaimedByWallet = claimCondition.supplyClaimedByWallet[_conditionId][_claimer];

        if (_currency != claimCurrency || _pricePerToken != claimPrice) {
            revert("!PriceOrCurrency");
        }

        if (_quantity == 0 || (_quantity + supplyClaimedByWallet > claimLimit)) {
            revert("!Qty");
        }
        if (currentClaimPhase.supplyClaimed + _quantity > currentClaimPhase.maxClaimableSupply) {
            revert("!MaxSupply");
        }

        if (currentClaimPhase.startTimestamp > block.timestamp) {
            revert("cant claim yet");
        }
    }

So my questions are:

Did they possibly create a Merkle Tree by importing all active addresses on Base Mainnet?
How do I verify that my wallet is allowed ? (It's public mint, so it's obviously that every addresses are eligible to mint)

